# Leaflet Custom Control - changing background colour of existing control

Tags: leaflet

I have a Leaflet map with two custom controls on it (`coverage1000Control` and `coverage2500Control`).

`coverage1000Control` is defined thus:

```
coverage1000Control =  L.Control.extend({

  options: {
    position: 'bottomleft'
  },

  onAdd: function (map) {
    container = L.DomUtil.create('input');
    container.type = "button";
    container.title = "1,000 ft";
    container.value = "1,000 ft";
    container.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    container.style.backgroundSize = "100px 30px";
    container.style.width = "80px";
    container.style.height = "30px";

    container.onclick = function(){
      clearMap();
      setHeight(1000);
    }
    return container;
  }
});
```

`Coverage2500Control` is defined in exactly the same way with the only difference is that `container.style.backgroundColor = "white";`.

I'd like to change the background color of each button when the user clicks on it to indicate which button was last clicked. In other words, when the map loads the `coverage1000Control` button is red as it's the default. When the user clicks on the `coverage2500Control` button, `coverage1000Control` goes white and `coverage2500Control` goes red.

I've tried putting `coverage1000Control.container.style.backgroundColor = "white"` in the `container.onclick` but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to change the background color of an exising Leaflet control and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

In the end I figured out that I could add a unique 'id' to my container definitions and then use:

```
document.getElementById("1000").style.backgroundColor = "white";
```

to change them.  Sometimes the simplest solution can elude you until you go away, walk the dog and then come back and look at it afresh !